# How to call abort() on data-remote=true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a navigation bar with all calls set as `data-remote=true`. I want to abort the request if the user clicks on an other item on the navigation bar.
It seems I need to call `.abort()`, but how do I do this from a rails `link_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but you could probably save the XMLHttpRequest in an `ajax:beforeSend` callback and abort the previous request. Something like:

```
var currentRequest;
$('your-nav-items').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if (currentRequest) currentRequest.abort();
  currentRequest = xhr;
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I did a bind on the document and process the abort on my navigation function.